# I use find_elements and get_atribute, but how to do it by single request, to avoid "not attached" error?

Tags: python, selenium

I do this:

```
dialogs = [i.get_attribute('data-list-id') for i in
               self.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="im_dialogs"]/li[contains(@class, "nim-dialog_unread ")]')]
```

A "not attached" error can appear in this case. I want to find attributes immediately, without finding elements. What do you recommend?

Comment: Post error as full Traceback, and give the link of the site

Comment: No it doesn't make sense to find attribute without finding web elements.

Comment: @cruisepandey so how can I do if between when I find elements and when I get their attributes some events can happen?

Comment: Yes find the elements first in a list then iterate that list and then for each web element try to extract their attribute.

Comment: Also if you need help from community, try to share relevant html code or page url if public.

Answer (score 0):

"not attached" error occur because there's element which not have 'data-list-id' attribute

What about using xpath `and` property to filter element which not have 'data-list-id'

```
dialogs = [i.get_attribute('data-list-id') for i in self.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="im_dialogs"]/li[contains(@class, "nim-dialog_unread ") and contains(@local-name(), "data-list-id")]')]
```

Comment: I checked, all such elements have this attribute

Comment: @aab137 If you give full element code like `<div style='' something=''></div>`, then I will think about other solution. And to get precise answer, you can give url related with question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this instead :

```
for attr in self.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="im_dialogs"]/li[contains(@class, "nim-dialog_unread ")]'):
    print(attr.get_attribute('data-list-id'))
```

Comment: a problem can occur here: 1) driver finds a list of elements; 2) something changes wing browser; 3) get_attribute cannot do anything good

Comment: What do you mean ? those are not problem, that's a program execution flow. also did you try before commenting, please respect the answer and try and if there's any error let us know.